# Program will not move to second monitor

Tags: display

I am a student using a program to do practice questions.

The program is set up to run like the actual test program in that it will take up the whole screen and block other applications. I have a lot of studying to do and would like to help my eyes out by opening it on the bigger monitor I have connected through VGA but I cannot drag it over nor get it to open there first.

If possible I want to avoid mirroring. Is there a way I can arange which monitor is the primary or something similar?

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose here that you should be prevented from consulting online material during the tests? In that case mirroring will be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by dragging the menubar to the bigger monitor in `System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement`. My guess is that the app will display it's main content on the monitor with the menubar assigned to it.

I worked on software that did this many years ago and this would have worked for that program.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mavericks (10.9)? It gives you menu bars on each display. You can set one app to go full screen while the other remains in its default state. This has turned out to be one of those features that I've found most beneficial in this release.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5891